# How to retrieve the list of a function's parameter's types in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a function

```
function add (...nums: number[]): number {
  return nums.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
}
```

how do I grab this signature? so that I can use it here

```
function subtract (
  sum: ReturnType<add>, 
  ...args: [/* <-- Here I want to grab the same type as add's arguments */]
): number {
  return args.reduce((running, next) => running - next  , sum)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterst)

> **Parameters<T>**
>
> Constructs a tuple type of the types of the parameters of a function type T.

```
function subtract (
  sum: ReturnType<typeof add>, 
  ...args: Parameters<typeof add>
): number {
  return args.reduce((running, next) => running - next  , sum)
}
```

Comment: Can we also slice this parameter from a certain position?

Comment: Check my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62948624/how-to-extract-varargs-argument-from-a-record-type-in-typescript

Comment: Thanks for pointing me there, yeah you nailed the question for me, what I want to ask is is exactly that, though I don't believe the current accepted answer is good enough.