# How to extract varargs argument from a record type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have the variable `x` defined as follows:

```
function foo (a: string, ...nums: number[]): string {
  return a;
}
const x: Parameters<typeof foo>

// Inferred: const x: [string, ...number[]]
```

Now, I want to extract the string and the numbers with the correct types.
For string, I have:

```
const sExplicit: Parameters<typeof foo>[0] //easy to specify
const sInferred = x[0]                     //type inferred correctly
```

I want to declare variable holding all the numbers. How can I do it?

I tried the following:

```
const numsExplicit: ??? Howto specify the type
const numsInferred = x.slice(1) // incorrectly inferred as (string | number)[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lookup type is by `number | string` only.

I would add the array myself:

```
function foo (a: string, ...nums: number[]): string {
 return a;
}
declare const x: Parameters<typeof foo>[1][];
```

Comment: How about assigning the value? Can I be do anything smarter than `const nums = x.slice(1) as any as Parameters<typeof foo>[1][]`

Comment: @Lesiak thanks for pointing me here, I think I'm also looking for that smarter solution than a reconstruction of the type.